# I can not load CSV file using Google Colab

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

```
car_sales = pd.read_csv("/content/sample_data/car-sales.csv")
car_sales
```

> The error:
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 1 # Import "../data/car-sales.csv" and turn it into a DataFrame
> ----> 2 car_sales = pd.read_csv("/content/sample_data/car-sales.csv")
> 3 car_sales
>
> 9 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in
> pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd1 in position
> 8: invalid continuation byte

The file is saved in my /content/sample_data and the path is correct.
[image]

Comment: can you share `car-sales.csv` ?!

Comment: `pandas` finds the file but then gets an error when trying to decode with UTF-8. Do you know what encoding the file uses? You could potentially open the file in binary mode, read the first, say 64 bytes and post that. Then we could start guessing.

Comment: Please don't be so unpolite as to delete your recent question. At least let people know whether you have solved your problem, and if their comments were helpful, or why you otherwise deleted your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try including an encoding param in your call, such as `latin1` or `iso-8859-1`

Like so: `pd.read_csv("/content/sample_data/car-sales.csv",encoding='latin1')`

Try various encodings until you find the right one

EDIT:
You can also try `encoding_errors='ignore'`

Answer (score 1):

try using this

```
car_sales= pd.read_csv('car-sales.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

or change the encoding format

```
encoding = "cp1252"
encoding = "ISO-8859-1"
```

if it still not work then the csv file might not saved in a proper encoding save it in UTF-8 encoding

If none of this works kindly share the csv file in order to carry a investigation on the file

Comment: We know for sure its not utf-8 so your first example isn't going to work.

Comment: ya you are right but to make him understand the encoding syntax i wrote that